# Use jQuery to select all asp:CheckBoxes in a RadGrid under same 'ParentId'

Tags: jquery, .net, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid which is composed of rows of checkboxes and text.  I have a situation where in one case I want to allow a user to select only one of two boxes that are 'nested' under an 'uncheckable' heading.  With the radgrid i do this by setting a 'ParentId' attribute.  The rendered html looks like:

```
<span ParentId="1">
<input id="actionCheckBox....
...
<span ParentId="1">
<input id="actionCheckBox....
...
<span ParentId="0">
<input id="actionCheckBox....
...
...
...
```

I would like to use jQuery and do something like

```
$('[id$=actionCheckBox]').bind("click", function() {
    if $(this).parent() span has attribute "ParentId"
    $(grabAllCheckBoxesWithParentId="1").uncheckall
    $(this).attr(':checked')
});
```

I thought I was getting close with this:

```
$('[id$=actionCheckBox]').bind("click", function() {
    if( $(this).parent('span[ParentId*="1"]') ){
        alert("hi"); 
    }
});
```

but no luck (I see the alert on ALL checkboxes in the grid, not just the ones in the ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).parent("span[ParentId='1']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$("#<%=RadGrid1.ClientID%> span[parentId='1']:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```